# Error when initializing Emacs

Tags: init-file, debugging, start-up

This is what I get when starting `Emacs` from terminal with  `emacs --debug-init`. I don't know the reason why emacs suddenly started to not working.

> ```
> Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument listp <!DOCTYPE)  
> package--read-archive-file("archives/gnu/archive-contents")  
> package-read-archive-contents("gnu")  
> package-read-all-archive-contents()   package-initialize()  
> eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil
> "/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer
> position 170  
> load-with-code-conversion("/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/init.el"
> "/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)  
> load("/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/init" t t)   #[0
> "\205\266�    \306=\203�\307\310Q\202?�   \311=\204�\307\312Q\202?�\313\307\314\315#\203*�\316\202?�\313\307\314\317#\203>�\320\321\322!D\nB\323\202?�\316\324\325\324\211#\210\324=\203e�\326\327\330\307\331Q!\"\325\324\211#\210\324=\203d�\210\203\247�\332!\333\232\203\247�\334!\211\335P\336!\203\201�\211\202\214�\336!\203\213�\202\214�\314\262\203\245�\337\"\203\243�\340\341#\210\342\343!\210\266\f?\205\264�\314\325\344\324\211#)\262\207" [init-file-user system-type delayed-warnings-list user-init-file
> inhibit-default-init inhibit-startup-screen ms-dos "~" "/_emacs"
> windows-nt "/.emacs" directory-files nil "^\\.emacs\\(\\.elc?\\)?$"
> "~/.emacs" "^_emacs\\(\\.elc?\\)?$" initialization format-message
> "`_emacs' init file is deprecated, please use `.emacs'" "~/_emacs" t
> load expand-file-name "init" file-name-as-directory "/.emacs.d"
> file-name-extension "elc" file-name-sans-extension ".el" file-exists-p
> file-newer-than-file-p message "Warning: %s is newer than %s" sit-for
> 1 "default"] 7]()   command-line()   normal-top-level()
> ```

Comment: That's something in your init file related to package repositories initialization. Maybe you forgot to quote something, or, alternatively, quoted something that wasn't supposed to be quoted. Anyways, after this error happens, try printing the value of `package--read-archive-file` by pressing `M-:` followed by the variable's name and paste the response here.

Comment: I did not make any alteration in my init file. And sorry but I don't know how to print the value of package--read-archive-file. Do you mean doing `M-x package--read-archive-file`?

Comment: When I do `M-x package--read-archive-file("archives/gnu/archive-contents")` RET the result is no match.

Comment: Might be a problem on the remote end, it looks like it's reading some HTML as elisp.

Comment: I tried with an year old `init.file` and the result was the same. What is the "remote end"? Should I reinstall Emacs?

Comment: Pressing `M-:` will prompt you to enter an ELisp expression. The name of the variable is such an expression. Once, after you enter the name of the variable, you press `RET`, Emacs will evaluate the expression and print the result (in your case: the value of the variable). But, as npostavs said: it seems like you are getting an HTML response where this wasn't expected.